# MiniZinc, Gecode remove solution separators

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

I have a minizinc model for which I want to find all solutions (I use gecode) then print statistics, this is easy:

```
mzn-gecode -as foo.mzn
```

but this model will generate thousands of solutions and a separator is printed for each solution:

```
----------

----------

----------

----------
==========
```

I need to remove these separators and only print the statistics. Is there a way?

==Update==

I was able to solve this by changing the Gecode source in

```
gecode/flatzinc/flatzinc.cpp
```

where i removed

```
out << "----------" << std::endl;
```

Maybe there is a better solution, but this worked great for me.

Answer (score 2):

```
--soln-sep <s>, --soln-separator <s>, --solution-separator <s>
        Specify the string used to separate solutions.
        The default is to use the FlatZinc solution separator,
        "----------".
```

adding `--soln-sep <s>` overwrites standard separator

Answer (score 1):

These separators are shown because you don't have any output statement for the variables.

E.g.

```
output [
  show(x) ++ "\n" ++ show(y)
];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I only want to print statistics. I have commented out my output, even with output []; empty the separators are printed.

There are so many solutions that it would take a long time to print it all. However I was just able to solve it by changing the Gecode source (removing the separator prints). I will update my question.

Comment: Some year ago Gecode/fz had an option --print-last (or something like that) which only printed the last solution. That was quite handy sometimes, but it was later removed for some reason (perhaps compliance with the MiniZinc Challenge flags).

Comment: `-a` prints all solutions found, so the line of dashes (empty solution output) gets repeated.